# minikube on macos with m1 darwin without docker

Tags: mac-osx, podman, arm, minikube

Ok, in my search for a development environment **without docker desktop**, I am exploring [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/).

The issue is that minikube (at the time of writing) **cannot run on macos with m1** chip because **hyperkit is not supported yet on darwin** acrhitecture.

I also tried to use the (as of the time of writing) experimental podman driver without success.

Has anybody been successful at running minikube on macos (Monterey) with M1 chip without docker desktop?

Comment: I don't use macOS so this is a wild guess. Maybe [__lima__](https://github.com/lima-vm/lima) could be used? https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12508#issuecomment-974646099

Comment: Please review this page, [Using Minikube on M1 Macs](https://itnext.io/using-minikube-on-m1-macs-416da593ba0c) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71579753/16922342) in SO that is related with your question.